# Getting 'Cannot Post' error message when trying to delete a document from mongoose using node js, express, ejs and method-override

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

Have been stuck with this problem for two days now. Trying to implement a delete function for a story collection. Using Node js, express, mongoose, ejs and method-override. Getting a 'Cannot POST' error message. Strangely, by code seems identical to a number of different sources (videos, articles etc) but is not working. Unable to find my error(s) no matter how much I try... Any help would be very much appreciated!

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require("../config/auth");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

const methodOverride = require("method-override");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));


const db = require("../config/keys").MongoURI;

const Story = require("../models/Story");
const { networkInterfaces } = require("os");
const { format } = require("path");
const User = require("../models/User");
const { route } = require("./users");

// Read Page

router.get("/read", async function (req, res, next) {
  var theGenre = "";
  userId = "";

  // If URL contains genre variable then find story by theGenre
  if (req.query.genre) {
    theGenre = req.query.genre;
    theStories = await Story.find({ genre: theGenre });
  }
  // Otherwise, find all stories
  else {
    theStories = await Story.find();
  }

  // Display user name if logged in

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    // Get user id from database
    userId = req.user.id;
    res.render(path.resolve("views/read"), {
      loggedIn: true,
      name: req.user.name,
      firstStory,
      theStories,
      userId,
    });
    return next();
  } else {
    res.render(path.resolve("views/read"), {
      loggedIn: false,
      name: "",
      firstStory,
      theStories,
    });
  }
});

// Delete Story

router.delete("/:id", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Delete Story " + req.params.id);
});

module.exports = router;
```

read.ejs

```
<% theStories.forEach(function(story){ %>
<div class="story">
  <p><%= story.story %></p>
  <% if (story.auther) {%>
  <!-- Display auther name -->
  <p class="authersign"><%= story.auther %></p>
  <!-- If auther didn't not sign display 'Anonymous' -->
  <% } else { %>
  <p class="authersign">Anonymous</p>
  <% } %>
  <!-- Display genre -->
  <p class="authersign"><%= story.storyGenre %></p>
  <p class="authersign">
    <!-- Display Creation Date -->
    <% const parseDate = Date.parse(story.createdAt); %> <% var newDate = new
    Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day:
    '2-digit'}).format(parseDate); %> <%= newDate %>
  </p>
  <!-- If user is logged in and user ID is the same as storyUserId then create delete button -->
  <div class="deleteButton">
    <% if (loggedIn = true && userId==story.userId) {%>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">
      Delete Story
    </button>

    <div id="id01" class="modal">
      <!-- <span
        onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"
        class="close"
        title="Close Modal"
        >&times;</span -->
      >
      <form
        class="modal-content"
        method="POST"
        action="/theStories/<%= story.id %>?_method=DELETE"
      >
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Delete Story</h2>
          <p>Are you sure you want to delete your story?</p>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="deletebtn">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <% } %>
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a POST request instead of a DELETE. DELETE requests are not supported in HTML4. You also set the method to a POST in the form tag and that's why your code wasn't working.

Comment: Thank you @SupaCal. But I thought that's exactly what method-override is supposed to do: switch the post to a delete. I have followed a number of examples like this. And if I call POST instead of DELETE - how would the document end up deleted? Many thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: HTTP verbs are not very strict and are made to make it so you don't have to put the method in the URI. You can delete a resource using any kind of request so for compatibility reasons you could just change the backend to accept any method for an end point by using `router.all` and you can have any method do the same thing. TL;DR HTTP methods are vanity [to some extent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Security)

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked:

```
router.delete("/:id", function (req, res) {
  Story.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
  req.flash("success_msg", "Your story has been deleted");
  return res.redirect("read");
});
```